# How to add integer to integers in array

Tags: java, arrays, list, addition

What I'm trying to accomplish is adding `1` to the all the numbers in `shipX` array list, question is, how? I want to do this when the method `move()` is called, but how would I make this happen, as I'm new with arrays

```
class Ship
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int shipX[] = {500,485,500,515,500};
        int shipY[] = {500,485,455,485,500};
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillPolygon(shipX, shipY, 5);
    }
    public void move()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You Should use ArrayList<int> instead of int array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, you will have to move your arrays for points outside the local scope of `paint()` and into the class so that `move()` has access to the current values. You would increment in the `move()` method and call whatever routine you use to redraw your component.

```
class Ship
{
    //make your polygon points members of the class
    //so that you can have state that changes
    //instead of declaring them in the paint method
    int shipX[] = {500,485,500,515,500};
    int shipY[] = {500,485,455,485,500};
    //set these to the amount you want per update. They can even be negative 
    int velocityX = 1;
    int velocityY = 1;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillPolygon(shipX, shipY, 5);
    }

    public void move()
    {
        //add 1 to each value in shipX
        for (int i=0; i<shipX.length; i++)
        {
            shipX[i] += velocityX;
        }
        //add 1 to each value in shipY
        for (int i=0; i<shipY.length;i++)
        {
            shipY[i] += velocityY;
        }
        //call whatever you use to force a repaint
        //normally I would assume your class extended
        //javax.swing.JComponent, but you don't show it in your code
        //if so, just uncomment:
        //this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Although I should point out that the `repaint()` method on `JComponent` does need to be called from the correct Swing thread, as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015833/2175939) answer.

If you are also trying to animate the movement, you can check out the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) on Swing timers to call your `move()` method on a schedule. You could also use an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) on a button to either control the `Timer` or on a button to move the object manually once per click.

Comment: @BrandonG I made a change to give you a velocity in both the X and Y directions. You can set them manually or adjust them dynamically elsewhere in your code

Comment: Exactly what im looking for, im not experienced with arrays at all, so this was a big help with my future projects and this one. Its hard to transition from a rect moving to a polygon! But one last thing, if I wanted to slow it down, could I just change I++ to I--

Comment: @BrandonG changing the code to `shipX[i]--` won't slow down your movement, it would actually reverse its direction! To slow it down, you should modify the `velocityX` and `velocityY` values (but negative will reverse direction, not decrease). If `1` still goes too fast, I recommend slowing down whatever you are using for a timer, or you could switch to using `floats`, but then we either have to re-work the math in the `move()` method, or we have to switch to using an implementation of [`java.awt.Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html) (not a bad idea)

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is iterate through the array and modify the value of each index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shipX.length; i++)
{
    shipX[i]++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the numbers one by one...

```
for (i=0; i<shipX.length; i++)
{
   shipX[i]++; // same as shipX[i] = shipX[i] +1
}

for (i=0; i<shipY.length;i++)
{
   shipY[i]++;
}
```

Comment: `shipY.length()`? Have you tested that code.  It's a property, not a method.

Comment: You are right i should be (i=0; i<shipY.length;i++)